# Grouping Columns in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that has 6 or 7 columns that are all related. I would like to group them all under one header, to show this relation. Each column would additionally have its own additional header (C1, C2, C3...) For example,

```
==========================================
                 Group Name              |
==========================================
 C1  | C2  | C3  | C4  | C5  | C6  | C7  | 
==========================================
     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 
     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to mege that is like Excel's merge and center option. You can search for help on Google docs help, but here is a link for help on merging [Google docs merge](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=141104).

[image: google docs merge]